# Encrypt/Decrypt strings with RSA .NET

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

.NET 6 project has the following class

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

internal sealed class EncryptionService
{
    private readonly RSAParameters _rsaParameters;

    public EncryptionService(RSAParameters rsaParameters)
    {
        _rsaParameters = rsaParameters;
    }

    public string Decrypt(string encryptedText)
    {
        using RSA rsa = RSA.Create(_rsaParameters);

        byte[] plainTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);

        byte[] decryptedTextBytes = rsa.Decrypt(plainTextBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(decryptedTextBytes);
    }

    public string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        using RSA rsa = RSA.Create(_rsaParameters);

        byte[] plainTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(plainText);

        byte[] encryptedTextBytes = rsa.Encrypt(plainTextBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedTextBytes);
    }
}
```

The `RSAParameters` is provided and no problem with that 
when I pass string `a` to encrypt it, I get the following exception

> System.FormatException : The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

This exception is raised from `Convert.FromBase64String` method and I understand that.

My Question actually is: how I can convert the string parameter to the byte[] that is needed by the RSA class?

**NOTE: `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` does not work, it throws another exception**

Comment: If you want to supply a plaintext string then why are you calling `Convert.FromBase64String(plainText);` when you're not supplying a base64 string? The normal flow is such cases is plaintext string -> utf8 encode to bytes -> encrypt -> base64 **encode**, and then to reverse base64 **decode** -> decrypt -> utf8 decode to string.

Comment: I do NOT want to supply base64, I just want a way to convert string to byte[] array that is acceptable by RSA.Encrypt method

Comment: Also RSA encryption is only suitable for very small plaintexts. Normally it used to encrypt symmetric keys that are in turn used to encrypt the plaintext. This is called [Hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Comment: I tried this flow, but as I said in the question it throw another exception, Give UTF8 bytes to Encrypt method is not good idea as I made a lot of research, everyone said, that I should not do that

Comment: Yeah I read about that, that I should use only small strings, but I am not sure what is the alternative, my strings will be very very long

Comment: Hybrid encryption can used to encrypt very long strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I reached and that worked for me

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

internal sealed class RSAEncryptionService
{
    private readonly RSAParameters _rsaParameters;

    public RSAEncryptionService(RSAParameters rsaParameters)
    {
        _rsaParameters = rsaParameters;
    }

    public string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        using RSA rsa = RSA.Create(_rsaParameters);

        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);

        byte[] encryptedTextBytes = rsa.Encrypt(plainTextBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedTextBytes);
    }

    public string Decrypt(string encryptedText)
    {
        using RSA rsa = RSA.Create(_rsaParameters);

        byte[] plainTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);

        byte[] decryptedTextBytes = rsa.Decrypt(plainTextBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);

        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedTextBytes);
    }
}
```